# Upgrading to ffmpeg version 6 in Ubuntu Server 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Is there an easy way to upgrade ffmpeg in Ubuntu? I have version 5.1.1 and want version 6. On Mac I have version 6 by default.

I have tried literally everything I could think of. Snap install,adding random repo lists. It seems to be very difficult. Ubuntu package managing really sucks

Comment: Because of "Ubuntu package managing really sucks" and/or beacuse you're using an outdated, unsupported, release that should have been upgraded a long time ago? This is what's available for the latest LTS release (22.04): https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&keywords=ffmpeg

Comment: *I got downvoted before adding that part* No, you didn't. At the time of this writing, some 10 minutes after your whinning, there are still ZERO edits in your question.

Comment: 1. This is SuperUser, not StackOverflow. 2. The question is of very low quality, asking about outdated system with EoL, in a way that encourages opinion-based answers on top.

Comment: @Destroy666 And the linked Q&A is from almost 10 years ago, many things were changed. Even if they weren't it wouldn't be applicable as that one mentions a **second** or subsequent edit NOT changing the original timestamp if done within 5 minutes. There's still ZERO edits in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't have in the 1st place IMO - questions about outdated things are generally worthless I'd say, as they'll affect very low number of people looking for a solution, plus they further encourage staying on those versions. Upgrading your system is how you should proceed as you may encounter a lot more issues.

Comment: As above and again, the release upgrade is strongly doscouraged in this situation. Backups and installing from scratch the current LTS is what you should do (and then add the PPA as the answer says). And re: edits: Edited questions like this one https://superuser.com/questions/1825477/how-to-move-files-that-have-the-same-file-name-but-different-extension-to-same-f clearly show "edited X time ago" which is a link to all the editing history. Where's yours exactly?

Comment: Well, you got your info, you can safely remove the question and get rid of minus points. I also dislike if people downvote without explantation, which improves barely anything, but nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

See the article
[FFmpeg 6.0 Released! How to Install in Ubuntu 22.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/03/ffmpeg-6-0-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04/).

Your problem is the PPA. The article recommends this
[unofficial PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg6)
for FFmpeg 6.

In a nutshell, these are the steps to follow :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ffmpeg6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
ffmpeg --version
```

Comment: Thanks, my issue is https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntuhandbook1/ffmpeg6/ubuntu kinetic Release gets a 404 not found. I think this is because I'm on 22.10 but terrified to upgrade as this is a production server. when I do `do-release-upgrade` it basically tells me not to proceed.

Comment: Yes, the PPA is for 22.04 only. You have the version you want already in the official repositories of the current non-LTS 23.10 release. And indeed is a very bad idea to do online release upgrades to 22.10. It would have to be 22.10 > 23.04 (also EoL) > 23.10 (then in April to 24.04 LTS that has 5 years support). It's ALWAYS a bad idea to use non-LTS for production and keeping them beyond their due date is simply irresponsible. Hence the downvotes, I suppose.

Comment: And I regret upvoting this answer because it's wrong (cf. above).